# How can I resize a mask with OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I would like to obtain a mask for a small (resized) image (800x600). Then I would like to resize the mask and apply it to the larger image (3000x2000). What would be the best practice for this purpose?

Without resizing it works fine as follows where `mask`is 800x600

```
mask2 = np.where((mask==1) + (mask==3),255,0).astype('uint8')
output = cv.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask=mask2)
```

With resizing I also see a rectangle (unwanted) which I have only drawn to the image but not mask. `mask` is 800x600 while `mask2` and `img3` are 3000x2000

```
mask2 = cv.resize(mask,dsize=(ih,iw),interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
mask3 = np.where((mask2==1) + (mask2==3),255,0).astype('uint8')
output = cv.bitwise_and(img3,img3,mask=mask3)
```

I would like to know whether the problem is related with `cv.resize`.

There are the images of the two outputs. Correct output:

[image: Correct output]

Wrong output (see the rectangle around the face):

[image: Wrong Output]

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: It does not throw an error, but the resulting mask is different than the original (small) mask.

Comment: Is it possible to share the image and the mask as well?

Comment: if your new mask is not the same as small mask then its not being interpolated properly, how did you verify the result of interpolation?

Comment: I have tried other interpolation methods and changing it to INTER_NEAREST solved the problem. Thank you for all the help.